# Is it possible to use Native SQL queries using micronaut hibernate-gorm?

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails-orm, micronaut

I've created micronaut project using hibernate-gorm which gives me GORM and Groovy functionality but when it does not have groovy.sql.Sql class and if i inject DataSource then it's not working too. Is it possible to use native SQL queries with micronaut hiberate-gorm?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. See the example:

```java
import grails.gorm.annotation.Entity
import grails.gorm.hibernate.HibernateEntity

@Entity
class Planet implements HibernateEntity<Planet> {
    String name
}
```

In this case it is important to implement `HibernateEntity` and then you will have `findWithSql` method available as it is shown in the unit test below implemented using Spock framework:

```java
import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional
import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MicronautTest
import spock.lang.Specification

@MicronautTest
class PlanetSpec extends Specification {

    @Transactional
    void 'Planet is found when using native query'() {
        given:
        new Planet(name: 'Mars').save()
        new Planet(name: 'Earth').save(flush: true)
        when:
        def actual = Planet.findWithSql("select * from planet p where p.name = 'Mars'")
        then:
        actual.name == 'Mars'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that there is a SQLQuery method in hibernate that runs native query against database engine. have you tried it?